# Tree data structure library in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Can any one tell a Tree data structure in java-script library (not binary trees ) ,

im required the data structure to keep the data not for provide the UI implementation

Any idea?

Comment: Javascript is a scripting language, as such it is designed to "do something" and not "store something". One solution would be for you to use an XML structure to store your data and then use javascript to manipulate it as you wish.

Comment: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data talks about the DS used for constructing jsTree. You may find it appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for this we have started our own project http://code.google.com/p/orgjs/ with both logic and drawing